Notify Ubuntu/Gnome using script that application is busy to prevent power off
When using "Power Off" action in Gnome if there are some GUI applications with unsaved changes (for example, text editor) there will be label "Some applications are busy or have unsaved work".
I am looking for a way to set this "unsaved" status from command line. So I can integrate it into my workflow when I'm using tmux/neovim, to not accidentally power off PC when I have some sessions opened.

Found out that you can use gnome-session-inhibit tool to set flag for Gnome Session to "inhibit" some actions (logout in this case).
$ gnome-session-inhibit --app-id APP_ID --reason reason --inhibit logout --inhibit-only

The only catch is that for APP_ID you should use something that had .desktop file (see endSessionDialog.js#L173 for details). For example, you could use --app-id vim.
